# What is the meaning of "to die to self"?

Tags: meaning

> To explain the ten principles of ACT, the authors draw on the lives of Gandhi, Jesus, and Martin Luther King, Jr. as examples of leaders who embodied these principles in their lives and teachings. These principles are based on two underlying assumptions: (a) change requires making painful adjustments to one's behavior; and (b) change requires placing oneself in jeopardy - taking risks that put the common good above self-preservation. So, to paraphrase Gandhi and Jesus, the practitioner of ACT (Advanced Change Theory) seeks to "be the change you want to see in the world" by "**dying to self**".

What is the meaning of *die to self* in the above paragraph?

Comment: Can you link to your source, please?

Comment: I just have several sheets with the header of "Pochron: Advanced Change Theory Revisited"

Answer (score 2):

**Dying to self** is related to religion and expresses the essence of Christian life and is part of being born again. The old self dies and the new self comes. It is symbolistically expressed by baptism.

[Good read here](http://www.gotquestions.org/dying-to-self.html)